# Read content from PDF using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to read text from PDF file using expo and React Native. I used the below code to read but it's not working. On click of a button i use the DocumentPicker to select the PDF file and then i wanted to extract the text from the document alone. I am trying to create a app to read out the text for me.
But i am not able to do that. Thanks in advance.

```
    loadText = async()=>{
    //Alert.alert("load text triggered");
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
    if(result.type == 'success') { 
      // alert(result.uri);
        let contents = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri);
        //console.warn('content', contents);
        if(contents.length > 0){           
            //let res = base64.fromByteArray(this.stringToUint8Array(contents)); 
            //alert("t" + res);           
            this.setState({textToBeRead : this.atob(contents)});
            alert("test" + this.state.textToBeRead);
        }                      
      }
  };

    atob = (input) => {
  const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
  let str = input.replace(/=+$/, '');
  let output = '';

  if (str.length % 4 == 1) {
    throw new Error("'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.");
  }
  for (let bc = 0, bs = 0, buffer, i = 0;
    buffer = str.charAt(i++);

    ~buffer && (bs = bc % 4 ? bs * 64 + buffer : buffer,
      bc++ % 4) ? output += String.fromCharCode(255 & bs >> (-2 * bc & 6)) : 0
  ) {
    buffer = chars.indexOf(buffer);
  }

  return output;
}
```

Comment: vikasse have you find a solution?

Comment: No naomi not yet